# Making Websphere service start even before the application deployments start happening

Tags: websphere

I have an EAR deployed in WebSphere. EAR contains two WAR files in it.
As per the application's architecture, the second WAR is dependent on the service provided by the first WAR i.e) for the second WAR to be started it calls a service provided by first WAR.
Now, when I try to restart IBM Websphere on a whole it successfully deploys first WAR (but the port is no up yet) and goes on to deploy the second WAR. It is failing because of the fact that Websphere isn't UP yet and thus second WAR is not able to get response from first WAR.

Is there a way to make Websphere service getting started first and then start to deploy the applications in it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my requirement. 
In the "Startup behavior settings" of the application, enabling the "Launch application before server completes startup" makes the server to behave as expected.